# For loop logic to create names in powershell

Tags: powershell

$Count will be given. Need to get strings from the loop. Those string should be used as names to define

```
 $count= 4
 $volumenames=@(for ($i=1; $i -le $count ; $i++ ){$i})
#Now I need vol-1,vol-2,vol-3,vol-4 values to variables $vol_name_01,$vol_name_02,$vol_name_03,$vol_name_04
```

Comment: generally speaking ... you should NOT do that. [*grin*] you have a set of related items, so keep them in a collection. if you auto-build variable _names_ ... you need to keep track of them. **_don't do that.__* instead, use a collection to keep them in and access them as needed from inside the collection by iterating OR by index.

Comment: Use a hashtable instead